# Kotlin Flows: Cancel API request when activity goes to background or navigates to another screen

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I've seen an example where `stateIn` is being used with StateFlow to cancel the upstream but in the case of `ViewModel` the scope would be `viewModelScope` which only gets destroyed in `onDestroy` of the activity.

And the API goes ahead anyway, only solution what I've found is to call `viewModelStore.clear()` in `onStop` of my activity.

```
val uiState = productsUseCase.getProductsData()
    .map {
        when (it) {
            is Result.Error -> {
                DashboardState.Error(it.exception.message.toString())
            }
            is Result.Success -> {
                DashboardState.Success(it.data.products)
            }
        }
    }
    .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(0), DashboardState.Loading("Loading Products"))
```

Logic where data is fetched

```
fun getProductsData(): Flow<Result<ProductsResponse>> {
    println("Fetching prods")
    return flow<Result<ProductsResponse>> {
        delay(3000)
        val productResponse = productService.fetchProducts()
        println("done Fetching prods")

        emit(Result.Success(productResponse))
    }.retry(2) {
        if (it is java.lang.Exception) {
            delay(DELAY_3S)
        }
        return@retry true
    }.catch {
        emit(Result.Error(it))
    }
}
```

Activity observing it as

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED) {
            productsViewModel.uiState.collect {
                when (it) {
                    is DashboardState.Error -> {
                        recyclerView.gone()
                        progressBar.gone()
                        tvErrorMessage.visible()
                        tvErrorMessage.text = it.error
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Error: ${it.error}")
                    }
                    is DashboardState.Loading -> {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Loading: ${it.loadingMessage}")
                    }
                    is DashboardState.Success -> {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Success: ${it.products.size}")
                        productsAdapter.submitList(it.products)
                        recyclerView.visible()
                        progressBar.gone()
                        tvErrorMessage.gone()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: You used `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000)`, so it will cancel it five seconds after the activity goes away. You can change this to 0 so it cancels immediately, but then there won't be a chance for it to keep going when the Activity is merely being recreated for a screen rotation.

Comment: @Tenfour04  changing it to 0 does not work, I guess it's because of the viewModelScope still being active.

Comment: No, that wouldn't be why. But the `productService.fetchProducts()` suspend function would have to cooperate with coroutine cancellation for it to work.

Comment: oh okay, any idea on how to achieve it?

Comment: It depends on how your API is designed. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative